# Which kernel moduules are really needed for docker installation?

Tags: linux, docker, embedded-linux

I am trying to install docker on a dragonboard 410c and am getting an error when trying to run `systemctl start docker`:

```
failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: failed to create NAT chain DOCKER: iptables failed: iptables --wait -t nat -N DOCKER: iptables v1.8.2 (nf_tables):  CHAIN_ADD failed (No such file or directory): chain PREROUTING
```

Having checked the necessary kernel modules using the script found here:
https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/contrib/check-config.sh

I found that I was missing: NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_IPVS and several other optional kernel modules. However, after adding this module I am still getting the same error after installing docker. Do I need other "optional" kernel modules?

Docker Version:

```
Version:           19.03.1    
API version:       1.40    
Go version:        go1.12.5    
Git commit:        74b1e89    
Built:             Thu Jul 25 21:26:42 2019
OS/Arch:           linux/arm64
Experimental:      false
```

Linux:

```
Linux linaro-alip 4.14.96 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem in my case was not missing kernel modules, but debian buster using nftables instead of iptables for nat as described here:
https://forums.docker.com/t/failing-to-start-dockerd-failed-to-create-nat-chain-docker/78269

The above mentioned solution (switching to legacy) worked for me:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy
sudo update-alternatives --set ip6tables /usr/sbin/ip6tables-legacy
```

Comment: The official Docker recommendation is still use to iptables-legacy, and on Debian and Ubuntu the old `iptables-nftables-compat` package hasn't been available for quite some time, so you either use `iptables-legacy` or you turn off iptables in Docker and manage the rules yourself with nftables (very complicated if you don't already know nftables).